# Why does this command work in SQL Server Management Studio but not from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following SQL command which reads the index fragmentation of my database called `Logik`:

```
USE Logik

SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
    ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType,
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes ind ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id
                    AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id
WHERE 
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, this works without a problem and returns the tables with their fragementation.

Yesterday, this also worked from PowerShell. I didn't change any code but today it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have an idea why?

`$Data` will stay empty:

```
param(
    [string]$connectionstring = "Server=some\instance;uid=sa;pwd=dfdfdfdf;Database=Logik;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=900;"
)

# Stop bei Fehler
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$database = "logik"

# Database Connection herstellen
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = $connectionstring
Try { $con.Open() } 
Catch { Throw $_.Exception.Message }

# command einlesen um Fragmentation zu lesen
$command = "
USE Logik
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType,
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind 
ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id
AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0"

# Command Zusammensetzen
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = $command
$cmd.Connection = $con
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 2000

# Execute Command
Try { $result = $cmd.ExecuteReader() }
Catch { Throw $_.Exception.Message }

# Output von Resultat
$Data = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Data.load($result)
```

The whole thing is strange because, after I load the data, I put it into another variable `$tables`, and I want to throw when `$tables` is empty.

I use this code to check if there is any data loaded, and it returns an empty row for `$tables`, but `$tables.count` returns 8. how is that possible?

```
# Logik Tabellen
$tables = $Data | ? { $_.avg_fragmentation_in_percent -ge 5 -and $_.IndexName -ne 0 }
if (!$tables) { Throw "Keine Datenbank gefunden, oder keine Höher als 5% Fragmentation" }
$tables.count ; $tables ; pause
```

Comment: USE should be followed by GO - to switch context indeed;

Comment: @revoua no. USE is a *batch* command understood by SSMS and sqlcmd only. It's NOT a T-SQL command

Comment: @SimonS `USE` shouldn't be used at all. Connect to the database you want in the first place. `USE` is a batch command understood by SSMS or sqlcmd, it's not a T-SQL command.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, still no luck with my script though

Comment: @SimonS `still no luck` isn't an error message. What's wrong this time? *Are* there any results when you run the query in SSMS? Are you sure there aren't any typos?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well yes it isn't, but there's also no error message ;). yes there are results in SSMS

Comment: @SimonS there's no point in catching an exception only to rethrow it either. It's the same as *not* catching it at all. As for this syntax : `Catch { Throw $_.Exception.Message }` What's `$_` in this case? Exceptions have an `InnerException` property, not just `Exception`. You'll have to execute the commands one by one and check the variables to find which line fails and why. *Did* the connection open? You can't be sure. I wouldn't even try this though, I'd try to find a way to *avoid* using ADO.NET inside powershell

Answer (score 1):

`USE` shouldn't be used at all. It's a batch command understood by SSMS or sqlcmd, not a T-SQL command.

In this case, the connection string connects to the `Logik` database already. There's no reason to use `USE` to switch to it.

Just use :

```
$command = "
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType,
...
```

If you want to use tables from different databases in the same query, use a three-part name, eg: `MyDatabase.dbo.ThatTableName`.

You should probably *not* use the ADO.NET library inside a Powershell script. Powershell won't complain if you misspell a variable name, it will create a new empty one.

Use the [SQL Server Powershell provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sql-server-powershell-provider) instead. This way you can write the following code :

```
Import-Module Sqlps -DisableNameChecking;
cd SQL\MyRemoteServer\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDatabase
$result=Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT @@VERSION;"
```

The `$result` variable will hold the results of the query after that.

If the query returns multile rows, or even a single one with multiple fields, you'll get back an array of objects with properties that match the columns.

The following query :

```
$tables=Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT * from sys.tables"
```

Will return the contents of the `sys.tables` table. You can access individual columns as properties. This script will return all table names :

```
$tables | %{ $_.name;}
```

Chained together :

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT * from sys.tables" | % {$_.name}
```

Comment: Thanks, no luck with my script though. strangely enough, there's no output in `$tables`. but if I use `$tables.count` it returns `8`. strange

Comment: No-one can help if you don't mention what's wrong, at least an error message. BTW why are you using the ADO.NET classes instead of the SQL Server Powershell cmdlets? Powershell won't complain if you misspell a variable, it will create a *new empty* one with the misspelled name

Comment: I explain my problem pretty clear in the question. I don't use sqlserver cmdlets because I'm not on the SQL server itself.

Comment: @SimonS unfortunately, you don't explain it. "It's empty" can simply mean that you have a typo. In fact, that's the reason for empty results 99% of the time. Notice the queries I provided. I *didn't* run them against the local server. On my machine I actually used the IP of the remote server